# Replacing words with token value

Tags: matlab, text, replace, tokenize

this is the code that I am running:

```
folder = 'C:\...';
textfiles = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.txt'));
nfiles = length(textfiles);
data = cell(nfiles);
fid_out = fopen('C:\...', 'w');
for i = 1 : nfiles %loop through all files in the folder
    fid = fopen(fullfile(folder, textfiles(i).name));
    line = fgetl(fid);
    fclose(fid);

s=textscan(text,'%s');

str=s{:};
[ii,jj,kk]=unique(str);
freq=hist(kk,(1:numel(jj))')';

    for j = 1:length(ii)
        word = ii{j};
        count = freq(j);
        fprintf(fid_out,'%d %s %d\r\n',i , word, count);
    end 

%i is the document index
end
```

my output text file looks like this (example):

```
1 A 3
1 and 4
1 the 6
2 A 4
2 anode 5
3 time 7
...
```

This is just an example of my output file, there are lots of words.

Now I want to replace the words with a number so that it looks like this:

```
1 1 3
1 2 4
1 35 6
2 1 4
2 3 5
3 36 7
...
```

So basically, I want to assign a number to a specific word (meaning 'A' will always = 1, and 'and' = 2, and so on) and replace the text with the number.

Comment: Can't you just use `j` in your `fprintf` statement?

Comment: Sorry, some text files down the list does not have the letter 'A' or any of the letters so shown in the example above, so a different word is going to have the token value 1. I should edit the output example I wrote above to make it clearer

Comment: with how many words are you working? is there any system behind the assignment of the numbers?

Comment: the text file contains 23602 words and I am trying to use it for this: http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/programs_data/importworddoccounts.html which according to requires this format of text file

Comment: You could use a [map container](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html). Add each new word to the container, so that you can store a unique token for each word.